# How to use javascript debugger instead of 'Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger'?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Suddenly I get the 'Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger' When I use debugger in Javascript/Jquery:
FOR EXAMPLE :

```
 function saveS() {
        if (position1 != " " || position1 != null) {
            **debugger;** //here it *should* be stopped.              
            $("#orderSaved").css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    }
```

I tried to Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer) and Disable Script Debuggung (Other) in the control panel -> internet options. But still I get the 'Just - In - Time' Popup.
How can I use the simple debbuger again ?

Comment: It seems, that you use some kind of extension for VS, if so, look at `TOOLS -> Extensions and Updates... -> Installed` then disable or remove it.

Comment: My installed are : Microsoft web developer tools, NuGet Package Manager, Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for javascript and Web Essentials 2012. What should I remove ? I remind that It all worked perfect and sudennly not..

Comment: Look at: [Just-In-Time Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6(v=vs.110).aspx)